# Output of ssss-combine cannot be captured

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to redirect the output of `ssss-combine` to a file, without success so far.

I tried the basics: `> file`, `2>&1 > file` and `tee file` but it always display on screen and nothing is put in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you did not specify the *exact* command you're executing, and as such it's hard to tell for sure, I assume that your command prints to the standard error file descriptor (a.k.a. stderr) rather than stdout.

The redirections `> file` or `| tee file` only redirect stdout but not stderr.

`2>&1 > file` doesn't do either what you're looking for. It first redirects the error to where stdout is at the moment, which is your terminal emulator, and *then* redirects stdout (and only stdout, not stderr) to a file.

You can use `2>file` to redirect stderr, or swap the two redirections in the previous example: `>file 2>&1` to redirect both streams into the same file. The order is important since they are evaluated left to right. This time you're first redirecting the output to the file, and then the error to the current location of the output (which is already that file).

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to use `script -c 'ssss-combine ...' output.txt` (Because ssss does not output to stdout)

Comment: This is presumably unnecessarily complex, and totally misses the point why redirection didn't work.